# Missing Oracle Java on my W8.1 dev machine

Tags: java, visual-studio-cordova

When I have succesfully run the CTP 1.1 I don't see the Oracle Java SDK that should have been installed on my Windows 8.1 machine. How come?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As you are new to SO, you might want to read the following help pages: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Did you get an error notifying you that Java had failed when the installer completed?

You can check C:\Program Files (x86) and see if a Java folder exists.